# How to get the sum of two vectors?

Tags: vector, position

I have three points with x and y values to start with. What I actually want is the position where the actual vector would go (look at image provided). 
Can you help me ? I tried around a little bit with atan2 and parallelograms, but unfortunately without success.

[image]

Comment: I'm rough on my Trig, but isn't this the same as adding the vectors? i.e. isn't your resultant vector (1050,600)?

Comment: Er, those look like view coordinates with a different origin; hang on, need to tweak the math

Comment: You can calculate the angle between two vector and compare if positive or not.

Comment: Your question is not clear? What is it that you are exactly looking for? Should your point ???,??? bisect or do you want to find out where it would be i.e. within the angle or outside it? Also ???,??? can be anywhere on that line if its the case of bisecting the two - so then what other criteria do you have?

Comment: This question is so wrong and the answer doesn't clarify that it's NOT about finding a bisector vector between two vectors. The image shows you're looking for a sum of vectors and that's what the accepted answer answers.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Again, I'll remind that I might be missing something, but I *think* this is pretty simple addition of vectors:

```
let point A be (700, 500)
let point B be (400, 400)
let point C be (650, 100)
let point D be (???, ???)

the vector from A to B is: (-300, -100) // i.e. x = B-A, 400 - 700, etc
the vector from A to C is: (-50, -400)
Adding these together yields the vector from A to D: (-350, -500).
Adding that vector to point A yields the coordinates of the point D: (350, 0)
```

Comment: Right, I always forget about adding vectors

Comment: propably : this only works , when converted to  normalized vectors (unit vectors)  -- which is not yet done in the code above.

Comment: also has problems, if parallel

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, find the equations of the bisectors of the angle between the lines

a1x + b1y+ c1 = 0 and a2x + b2y + c2 = 0.

A bisector is the locus of a point, which moves such that the perpendiculars drawn from it to the two given lines, are equal.

The equations of the bisectors are

a1x+b1y+c1/√a12+b12 = + a2x+b2y+c2/√a22+b22.

Simply adapt these equations to your particular case.