# How can I find the coordinates of the resulting vector so that I can display it on an image?

Tags: image, numpy, math

I try to calculate and display a point on an image. Suppose I have the following points:

```
A = (x1, y1)
B = (x2, y2)
C = (x3, y3)
```

I want to calculate the coordinates of the resulting vector between the vectors AB and AC. What I thought:

```
AB=(x2-x1,y2-y1)
AC=(x3-x1,y3-y1)
```

and the resulting vector would be

```
AD(for example)=(((x2-x1)+(x3-x1)),((y2-y1)+(y3-y1)))
```

I'm not sure I thought well mathematically, but my biggest problem is that the result does not match the image, the coordinates can give negative numbers after this calculation. How can I find the coordinates of the resulting vector so that I can display it on an image?
I also added a small image, to better understand what I'm trying to say:

[image: overview]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm so if I see it right you want something between mirror and projection ... As there is probably no guarantee than AB and AC are symmetrical ...

I would try this using vector math:

[image: overview]

```
ba = A-B
bc = C-B
E = B + bc* dot(ba,bc)/(|bc|^2)
D = E + (E-A)
D = 2.0*E - A
D = 2.0*(B + bc* dot(ba,bc)/(|bc|^2)) - A
```

Where `dot(a,b)=a.x*b.x+a.y*b.y` is scalar multiplication and `|a|^2=(a.x*a.x)+(a.y*a.y)` is vector size squared

So the `E` is perpendicular projection of `A` onto `BC` and `D` is mirror reflection of `A` around `E` and `BC` ...

Comment: Thanks a lot! That was what I was looking for! I solved the problem.

Comment: @CeraselaMardare glad to be of help ... I just assumed you do not want the real mirror but more of a projection so if ABD is smaller than ACE then also BDE will be smaller then CDE ...  so the geometric properties are still in the scale to image properties (for DIP/CV purposes)

Answer (score 2):

What you are doing is essentially adding two vectors, AD = AC + AB. So your image is correct if that is what you want to do. As for the negative numbers this depends on what your vectors are. The vector will be negative if it goes opposite the positive directions of your coordinate system.

Added an image to show how the vector AD is made graphically:

[image: img]

I recommend checking out some basic vector operations

EDIT: found similar topics:

[How to get the vector between two vectors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11417626/how-to-get-the-vector-between-two-vectors)